# What's `[]` in IP?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

[An article](https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/130383/malware/botenago-botnet-targets-dvr.html) I found used this notaion for an IP address:

> download a file named wget.sh from the IP address 136.144.41[.]169

what's the point of braces here and what's the difference between: `136.144.41[.]169` and `136.144.41.169`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.] is not part of the IPv4 address standard. It is simply 0-255 four times separated by periods.

I'm guessing the site had a formatting error.
[Original link](https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/130383/malware/botenago-botnet-targets-dvr.html)